# How to make 100% hard circles without blurred edges (photoshop)

Tags: anti-aliasing

I'm making a circle with a radius of 400 pixels, the edge of it looks like this:

[image]

But the look I'm trying to achieve is a circle with hard edges, meaning no transparency, the edge of it would then look like this:

[image]

So how do I do it?

Answer (score 3):

Circle fill is pretty simple. All you have to do is take the `Ellipse tool` and set the `Tool mode` to `Pixels` and turn `Anti-alias` off.

---

---

Circle stroke is not as simple. Now I'm not pixel art master, but I'd say that the best way in Photoshop might be this:

**Making a circle stroke manually**

1. Create circle `Shape`
2. Copy & paste
3. `Free transform` the second circle smaller (`Cmd + T`)
4. In Path operations: `Subtract front shape`
5. Right-click inside the document > `Define custom shape`

Just like I explained above, but this time take `Shape tool` and set the `Tool mode` to `Pixels` and turn `Anti-alias` off.

[image]

Note that in the gif, I had a small document zoomed to 300%, so the circle looks pretty rough. The bigger the circle, the better it looks.